# Magento-Add a field on default Registration form

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento v1.7.0.2 and have tried to add a Mobile field on registration form. I have amended the code(See code at below). However, the Mobile field still isn't shown on the registration form.

Is there anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!

**app\etc\modules\Mydons_Customer.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mydons_Customer>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <active>true</active>
        </Mydons_Customer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app\code\local\Mydons\Customer\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mydons_Customer>
            <version>1.7.0.0</version>
        </Mydons_Customer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <fieldsets>
            <customer_account>
                <mobile><create>1</create><update>1</update></mobile>
            </customer_account>
        </fieldsets>
        <models>
            <Mydons_Customer>
                <class>Mydons_Customer_Model</class>
            </Mydons_Customer>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <Mydons_Customer>
                <class>Mydons_Customer_Helper</class>
            </Mydons_Customer>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <customerattribute_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mydons_Customer</module>
                    <class>Mydons_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </customerattribute_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app\code\local\Mydons\Customer\Model\Entity\Setup.php**

```
class Mydons_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup extends Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup
{
    public function getDefaultEntities(){

        return array(

                'mobile'=>array(
                        'type'=> 'static',
                        'label'=> 'Mobile',
                        'visiable' => true,
                        'required' => true,
                        'sort_order' => 80,
                )
        );
    }
}
```

**app\code\local\Mydons\Customer\sql\customerattribute_setup\mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**

```
   $installer = $this;

    $installer->startSetup();


    $installer->addAttribute('customer', 'mobile', array(
        'label' => 'Mobile',
        'visible' => 1,
        'required' => 1,
        'position' => 1,
        'sort_order' => 80,        
    ));


    $installer->endSetup();

    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->loadByCode('customer', 'mobile');
    $forms= array('customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create', 'adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register');
    $customer->setData('used_in_forms', $forms);
    $customer->save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the corresponding templates to add the field you want in the register form.
In this case, `customer/form/register.phtml` and `persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`

Comment: Thanks @blmage, I have modified template on customer/form/register.phtml, customer/form/edit.phtml and persistent/customer/form/register.phtml. The 'Mobile' label is displayed but the textfield of the mobile isn't shown. Do you know why?

Comment: What code did you put in the templates to display the textfield ?

Comment: ,this is my code
`<li>
             <label for="mobile" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Mobile') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                 <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getMobile()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Mobile') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />
                </div>
            </li>`

Comment: Except that the `getCustomer()` may not be defined for each template (`getFormData()` is used instead on the register form), your code should work. At which place did you put it ?

Comment: thanks very much. it's working now. Since I'm new to Magento, I don't even know which table will store the Firstname/Lastname/Email/Mobile data once user registered. Would mind give some hint?

Comment: As those ones are varchar fields, in the `customer_entity_varchar` table (customers as well as products and categories, use EAV tables).
And to find out which attribute ID corresponds to which attribute, you can take a look at the `eav_attribute` table

Comment: there are fields(Firstname/Lastname/Email)in 'eav_attribute' table. But the 'eav_attribute' table don't have field called 'mobile'. Is there something wrong on the code so that the table 'eav_attribute' doesn't add 'mobile' field.

Comment: At least it seems that the call to `addAttribute` lacks the attribute type, that you could assign to `varchar` rather than `static`, as it would instead add a new field directly to the `customer_entity` table.
Also, the method `getDefaultEntities`s from the `Mydons_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup` is not used, nor it would be needed anyway, as you already use `addAttribute` in the install file.
Anyway, maybe you can open a new question for this, as it will be easier to read and answer :)

Comment: change validate email to some other because its not a email field

Comment: can we also use a select options instead of textbox for adding a new fields with the same method and the admin can add that select options from admin